# How to redirect output of external utility to the bottom area of gVim on Windows?

Tags: windows, vim, redirect

Is it possible to redirect output of external utility to the bottom area of gVim, so it should be displayed just like output of gVim built-in commands, like :ls or :registers ? There are plenty of tips how to read output of external tool into current buffer, or new tab, but I couldn't find the way to redirect it to the bottom area. I use GUI version of Vim 7.3 on Windows (gVim). Any advices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:echo system('dir')
```

Should get you what you describe.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought it should be trivial, but couldn't find this answer myself.